# Prove of some vector's differential relations

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis, tensors

I want to know how to prove these two relations:

$(V⋅∇)V=\frac12∇(V⋅V)−V×(∇×V)$

$(∇.sv)=(∇s.v)+s(∇.v)$

[These relations are from Bird's Transport Phenomena]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use Einstein notation and cartesian coordinates.
For the first one, let's compute $\vec{v} \times (\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{v})$:
$$\begin{align}
(\vec{v} \times (\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{v}))_i&=\epsilon_{ijk}v_j(\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{v})_k\\
&=\epsilon_{ijk}v_j\epsilon_{kpq}\partial_pv_q\\
&=\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{kpq}v_j\partial_pv_q\\
&=\epsilon_{kij}\epsilon_{kpq}v_j\partial_pv_q\\
&=(\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq}-\delta_{iq}\delta_{jp})v_j\partial_pv_q\\
&=v_q\partial_iv_q-v_p\partial_pv_i\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\partial_i(v_qv_q)-v_p\partial_pv_i\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\partial_i(\vec{v} \vec{v})-(\vec{v}\vec{\nabla})v_i
\end{align}$$

And if I'm right, your second identity is $\vec{\nabla}(s\vec{v})=(\vec{\nabla}s)\vec{v}+s(\vec{\nabla}\vec{v})$:
$$\begin{align}
\vec{\nabla}(s\vec{v})&=\partial_i(sv_i)\\
&=(\partial_i s)v_i+s(\partial_iv_i)\\
&=(\vec{\nabla}s)_iv_i+s(\vec{\nabla}\vec{v})\\
&=(\vec{\nabla}s)\vec{v}+s(\vec{\nabla}\vec{v})
\end{align}$$